# How to get a value (not create a string) dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display a value on React like this:

'If THING exists, then show THING'

So far I have

```
values.price ? `You'll pay ${values.price}` : null
```

What I need is get

```
values.price0 ? `You'll pay ${values.price0}` : null
values.price1 ? `You'll pay ${values.price1}` : null
values.price2 ? `You'll pay ${values.price2}` : null
values.price3 ? `You'll pay ${values.price3}` : null
```

That number will come from the props, so I am trying to do the following, but it doesn't work. How to go about fixing this?

```
values.price + props.id ? `You'll pay ${values.price + props.id}` : null
```

Comment: can you show what the output is?

Comment: `values["price" + index]` is what the duplicate of the previous question explained.

Comment: @Pointy now it makes more sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access properties as below ;

```
values[`${price}${props.id}`] ? `You'll pay ${values.price + props.id}` : null
```

or you can simply loop through keys

```
Object.keys(values).map(k => `You'll pay ${values[k]}`)
```